# My AdMob banner works with the test id but display anything with mine

Tags: android, admob, google-play-services

When I put the test banner id it displays well, but when I put mine nothing is displayed (I have a lot of requests but 0 impressions).

It's been two weeks since I set up my Admob account. I've been looking for hours and I can't find any solutions.

Here is my .xml :

```
<com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
    xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/adView"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    ads:adSize="BANNER"
    ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id" />
```

My .java :

```
MobileAds.initialize(this, "ca-app-pub-XXXXXXXXXX/YYYYYYYYY");

mAdView = findViewById(R.id.adView);
AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
```

And my Gradle file :

```
dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.constraintlayout:constraintlayout:1.1.3'

    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'

    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-messaging:20.1.6'


    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-ads:19.1.0'
}
```

Also I set up the metadata in the application of the `Manifest`...

What's wrong with it?

Thanks

Comment: Did you try `MobileAds.initialize(this);` without the id as it is already in the manifest?

Comment: Yes still not working :(

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in manifest file

```
<meta-data
android:name="com.google.android.gms.ads.APPLICATION_ID"
android:value="ca-app-pub-xxxxxxxxxxx~yyyyyyyyyyy" />  //publishers id
```

Comment: Your Admob account has been verified?

Comment: add Gradle file  'implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-ads:17.0.0' '

Comment: My account was activated 10 days ago.. And I tried to implement it but I have this error :

Comment: Duplicate class com.google.android.gms.internal.measurement.zzw found in modules jetified-firebase-analytics-impl-16.2.2-runtime.jar (com.google.firebase:firebase-analytics-impl:16.2.2) and jetified-play-services-measurement-base-17.1.0-runtime.jar (com.google.android.gms:play-services-measurement-base:17.1.0)

Comment: Ok I fix this error and add your gradle file implementation, but still not display :/